# single function call on click any label JInternalFrame Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am new to learning Java.

I am creating a JInternalFrame which have 28 labels in matrix forms in it. I want to change label text from **-** to **+** on click & vice versa.

[image]

I can do it adding EventListeners to each label one by one. But I want some simple solution in which I don't need to add eventlisteners for each label individually. A long ago I have tried same methodology on array of buttons in VisualBasic.

Comment: It means I need to create list of 28 labels manually once.

Answer (score 4):

> But I want some simple solution in which I don't need to add eventlisteners for each label individually

Why? You can share the MouseListener. Then you just add the listener to the label when you create the label. This is the better approach then trying to search for the clicked label after the fact.

For example:

```
MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        JLabel label = (JLabel)e.getComponent();
        label.setText( label.getText().equals("-") ? "+" : "-" );
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 28)
{
    JLabel label = new JLabel("-");
    label.addMouseListener( ml );
    panel.add(label);
}
```